# Change TextBlock.Inlines from Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, textblock, inlines

Is there any way to change the inlines from a BackgroundWorker?

I tried the following:

```
private void test()
    {
        var rows = GetDataGridRows(dgVarConfig);
        foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
        {
            TextBlock tb = cMatchEx.GetCellContent(r) as TextBlock;

            if (!syntaxWorker.IsBusy)
                syntaxWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new KeyValuePair<TextBlock, String>(tb, tb.Text));
        }
    }

    private void syntaxWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument == null)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        else
        {
            KeyValuePair<TextBlock, String> kvp = (KeyValuePair<TextBlock, String>)e.Argument;
            e.Result = new KeyValuePair<TextBlock, List<Run>>(kvp.Key, Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value));
        }
    }


    private void syntaxWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            KeyValuePair<TextBlock, List<Run>> kvp = (KeyValuePair<TextBlock, List<Run>>)e.Result;
            TextBlock tb = kvp.Key;
            tb.Text = "";
            kvp.Value.ForEach(x => tb.Inlines.Add(x));
        }
    }
```

And the syntax class:

```
public static class Syntax
{
    static Regex subFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(\)");
    static Regex sapFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(([^)]+)\)");
    static Regex strings = new Regex(@"\'[^']+\'");
    static Regex numerals = new Regex(@"\b[0-9\.]+\b");
    static Regex characteristic = new Regex(@"(?:)?\w+(?:)?");
    static Regex andOr = new Regex(@"( and )|( AND )|( or )|( OR )");
    static Regex not = new Regex(@"(not )|(NOT )");

    private static Brush[] colorArray;

    public static List<Run> Highlight(String input)
    {


        colorArray = new Brush[input.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            colorArray[i] = Brushes.Black;

        //Reihenfolge beibehalten!!
        assignColor(Brushes.Blue, characteristic.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Black, andOr.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Black, numerals.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Orange, strings.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.DeepPink, subFormula.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Green, sapFormula.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Green, not.Matches(input));


        int index = 0;

        List<Run> runList = new List<Run>();

        foreach (Char character in input)
        {
            runList.Add(new Run(character.ToString()) { Foreground = colorArray[index] });
            index++;
        }


        colorArray = null;
        return runList;
    }

    public static void Check(TextBlock textBlock)
    {

    }


    private static void assignColor(Brush brush, MatchCollection matchCollection)
    {
        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            int start = match.Index;
            int end = start + match.Length;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                colorArray[i] = brush;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I alway get this error: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I tried many different things: return the runList with progress changed, changed the static syntax class to a normal class.. but nothing worked, its always the same error.

I also tried to invoke it from the Backgroundworker.. that means call

```
    List<Run> runList = Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value);

this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        runList.ForEach(x => publicRunList.Add(x));
    }));
```

Anybody knows the problem?

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: RunWorkerCompleted where i want to add the inlines

Comment: Have you tried synchronization context?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: It is similiar as dispatcher but does not invoke UI thread's elements so roughly in short. This might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Comment: @ThomasKlammer give a try on `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` . .

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
tb.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    tb.Text = "";
    kvp.Value.ForEach(x => tb.Inlines.Add(x));
});
```

instead of

```
tb.Text = "";
kvp.Value.ForEach(x => tb.Inlines.Add(x));
```

Gui elements can only be accessed from the Gui thread. Using `Dispatcher.Invoke` ensures that the invoked action runs on it.

You are also creating `Run` objects in `Syntax.Highlight`. You also have to create Gui elements on the Gui thread. So you should also wrap this call in a dispatcher invoke:

```
e.Result = new KeyValuePair<TextBlock, List<Run>>(kvp.Key, Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value));
```

This should work:

```
//this runs synchronously
kvp.Key.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    e.Result = new KeyValuePair<TextBlock, List<Run>>(kvp.Key, Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value));
});

//this runs asynchronously
kvp.Key.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
    e.Result = new KeyValuePair<TextBlock, List<Run>>(kvp.Key, Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value));
}));
```

This probably defeats the purpose of why you wanted to use a `BackgroundWorker` in the first place. I'd suggest to change the interface of `Syntax.Highlight` to return a list of tuples with the string and the highlight color instead, and then create the `Run` objects on the Gui thread.

**Edit**:

As Gopichandar noted, using `BeginInvoke` executes the given Action asynchronously, so that would solve the freezing of the application. It would still take a couple of seconds until all elements are added to the Gui though.

Comment: @ThomasKlammer please check the latest edit, this should fix the problem

Comment: so, what do i need a backgroundworker for? Syntax.Highlight does take a while for 2000 entrys in the DataGrid. With this Method my UI Freezes

Comment: @ThomasKlammer as I wrote in the last paragraph, you should change the interface of `Syntax.Highlight` to return a list of tuples that contain the text and the according color.

Comment: @ThomasKlammer This way `Syntax.Highlight` can still run in another thread, but you can move the creation of `Run` objects to the UI thread.

Comment: i did that, the creation of run objects takes a couple of time so its still freezing :(

Comment: where should i add the "BeginInvoke"?

Comment: @ThomasKlammer have a look at the last code example, I've appended it to illustrate show you where to use BeginInvoke

Comment: i get the error message  `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: there is still a freeze of a couple of seconds.. is there no chance to build up the gui step by step? its not a problem if i see it build up, but the gui should never freeze, not even for 2 seconds

Comment: @ThomasKlammer sure there is, but this is probably enough material for another question.

Comment: @ThomasKlammer fixed the syntax error you mentioned

Comment: yep, a new thread would be possible. but i can only post every 90 minutes :D

Comment: @ThomasKlammer oh, didn't know there was a limit

Comment: @ThomasKlammer is the problem that you get the error `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.` now resolved for you? Or do you need additional information?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, only the thread that the UI element belongs to (i.e. the UI thread) can communicate with it. The DoWork part of the BackgroundWorker is executed in a different thread and thus cannot do anything UI-related. The same thing goes for Timers instead of BackgroundWorkers.

But if you create the BackgroundWorker with `var worker = new BackgroundWorker {WorkerReportsProgress = true};` then you can set an event handler for `ProgressChanged`. Inside your `_DoWork()`, you can then say: `(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress`, which will call your `ProgressChanged` event handler in the original thread, where you can manipulate the UI elements.

Full example:
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/multi-threading-with-the-backgroundworker/